# Image Not Going Where I Want It

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on an About Me page, and I want the text box to set to the left of the screen and a picture to run inline with the text, but for some reason I can only get the picture to show up underneath.  Could someone please tell me what I doing wrong? Thank you.

HTML

```
<div class="about_me">
<h2 class="about">about me</h2>
<p class="bio">I am a Front End Designer that hails from Cadillac, MI.  I have a deep understanding on HTML and CSS, and love designing and coding websites.  I enjoy taking your problems and turning them into solutions.  Whether you need a simple logo or an entire website, I can get it done for you.        </p>
 </div>

<div class="family">
<img src="images/family1.jpg" alt="family">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.about_me {width: 500px;
          height: auto;
          border:none;
          visibility: visible;
          right: 0%;
          opacity: 1;

          }

.about {font-size: 45pt;
        font-family: Zumba Fitness Official Typeface;}

.bio {font-family: arial;
      font-size: 14pt;
     }

.family {visibility: visible;
         left: 0%;
         opacity: 1;
        }
```

Comment: Oh, the sweet irony of about me pages and stackoverflow questions ☺

Comment: Irony indeed. The disrupt between that bio line and this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
.aboutme {float: left;}
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

add `display: inline-block;` to the `.about_me` and `.family` classes both, and remove left and right properties from the both classes. also add 'float: left;' to the `.about_me` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create class in left for image and right for text.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
<img style="float:right;">
```